# What should I do when I see weirdness going on with certain users?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have plenty of reputation, And so I don't particularly mind care, but it does seem awfully suspicious that the user *[vitas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1139641/vitas)* has 50/51 reputation, earned from answers posted about an hour prior to this writing.

Both questions are from the same user, [vitali ponomar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848550/vitali-ponomar). Both questions had accepted answers dated several days in the past. Both accepted answers lost an upvote in addition to the acceptance.

Even if I never get the 15 reputation back, it still seems unfair to me.

Answer (score 16):

There is no reason to open a meta topic about a specific user.

If you wish to open a meta topic about a *certain class of behavior* please do.

Otherwise, as person-who-changed-his-name-to-something-hilarious-and-festive-so-I-can't-tell-who-they-are-any-more said:

> Flagging is usually the best way of getting our attention. It doesn't particularly matter what you flag as long as you link both accounts and explain the unusual activity you've seen.

Don't ever hesitate to flag any user shenanigans that you see. We always follow up.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like that was a newly created sock puppet. I merged the accounts.

As Gamecat said, flagging is usually the best way of getting our attention. It doesn't particularly matter what you flag as long as you link both accounts and explain the unusual activity you've seen.

Answer (score 3):

It happens sometimes that users change their accepted answers.

Normally that is no problem. But if you have some serious doubt, you can always flag for a moderator.

Comment: That raises the question - how would you flag suspected sockpuppeteering? Flag one of the answers with "other", and reference the other one?

Comment: @EboMike There's no way to flag a user, but you can flag any of their posts instead. In this case flagging one of these answers would make sense.