# Is this a robot?

Tags: support, robots

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/975898/leon) has posted 3 posts now that I've seen. Two of which I've answered. They all start out exactly the same, go through major edits and s/he/it moves on to repeat the process.

The suspicious posts:

[Destroy timeout for HistoryRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788690/destroy-timeout-for-historyrecord)

[won't run, won't switch activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796835/wont-run-wont-switch-activities)

[Android Error "Application not installed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798527/android-error-application-not-installed)

Sorry, not sure if you can link to specific revisions other than `source` but if you look at those three posts, you'll see the progression that takes place.

What's happening here? Is this not human?

Comment: I don't think robots are capable of answering those comments like that.

Comment: Seriously, then what could be happening? It's bizarre!

Comment: "It didn't work."

Comment: Just read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118473/175199 from now on, I will only flag a post rather than writing up on Meta.

Comment: don't think it's a robot, just someone who don't know how to use the system.

Comment: No that's not robot,

Comment: "Application not installed" in Android... errr... what I meant to say was that no, that's definitely a human being. Case closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The questions are all different aside from the posting style and the user is responding to comments intelligently, so this looks to me more like the user's not learning from the edits than anything else.

**Update:** Nevermind; looking at first revisions of each post, it does seem like something odd's going on. I'll take care of it from here. Thanks for the lead!

P.S. You can link to a revision like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8796835/1). You can either create the URL manually (cause everyone loves doing that, right?) or by using the little chain icon beside the revision:

[image]

Comment: But the first version of the posts are all completely identical. Doesn't that raise some suspicion?

Comment: @TryTryAgain Ergh. You're right. This is kinda weird. I'll handle it.

Comment: Hope I don't lose the rep I gained...ha...kidding. Do what you have to do to keep the peace. Thanks :-) Happy to have helped.

Comment: Thanks for the info about how to link revisions,  d'uh. If anything can inevitably be publicly known, I'm curious about the outcome if you could post back with any update that would help satisfy a bit of my curiosities.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this user likes the layout of the first question and uses copy paste as a reminder. And it is saves because he doesn't rely his connection.

Comment: I did that with three Star Trek Voyager questions on Scifi that were about the same episode of Voyager. +1